# Confused About How JavaScript Closure Works

Tags: javascript, closures

I think this is a silly question, but given this JavaScript code....

```js
function outerFun()
{
 var a=0;
 function innerFun()
 {
  a++;
  alert(a);
 }
 return innerFun;  
}
var obj=outerFun();
obj();  //1
obj();  //2
var obj2=outerFun();
obj2();  //1
obj2();  //2
```

I understand why the result is 1 and then 2 in the first two calls of obj(), but I am confused as to why obj2() is returning 1 and not returning 3 after calling obj() twice.

Answer (score 3):

Because each time you call `outerFun()`, you are creating a different and new execution context, and so `innerFun` isn't really the same thing, as each function reference to `innerFun` you return from `outerFun` is in a different context, a context with its own variables.

```
function outerFun()
{
 var a=0;
 function innerFun()
 {
  a++;
  alert(a);
 }
 return innerFun;  
}
var obj = outerFun();
var obj2 = outerFun();
console.log(obj === obj2);
// Not equal, because innerFun is a different innerFun for each function call,
// as it is the same function name, returned from the same function,
// but in a different context.
obj();  //1
obj();  //2
obj2();  //1
obj2();  //2

// Call obj twice, it'll increase to 4.
// While calling obj2 once again, leaves it at 3.
// This way you can know that obj and obj2 are not modifying
// the same variables.
// They are independent of each other.
obj(); // 3
obj(); // 4
obj2(); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `outerFun()`, it creates a new function and returns it. It does this every time you call it. And each function it returns is actually a brand new function, unrelated to the ones created when you called it before, even though the code inside them is the same.

When you reach this statement...

```
var obj2=outerFun();
```

...you're actually creating a new object that has its own copy of `a` in its parent scope. So you actually *would* get three if you called `obj();` again after instantiating `obj2`. They each have their own `a` variable. Hopefully this modification to the example makes sense:

```
function outerFun()
{
    var a=0;
    function innerFun()
    {
        a++;
        alert(a);
    }
    return innerFun;  
}
var obj=outerFun();
obj();  //1
obj();  //2
var obj2=outerFun();
obj();  //3
obj();  //4
obj2();  //1
obj2();  //2
obj();  //5
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `outerfun ()` second time, new `a` is defined with value 0.